# Saving List<EntityProxy> in GWT RequestFactory

Tags: gwt

I want to save a list of entity objects in RequestFactory. Most of the time, i can find

RequestContext with Save(EntityProxy) alone and not with Save(List of EntitProxy).

Is it possible to do in GWT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your RequestContext, add a method like

```
Request<Void> save(List<MyEntityProxy> proxies);
```

and have that map to a method like

```
public void save(List<MyEntity> entities)...
```

in your service class.

This may need to be static, depending on how you are using locators, and what kind of `Request` you are using. If this isn't working, can you post the full RequestContext (including annotations) and the error that occurs? It might give a hint as to why it isn't working correctly.